# Can dedicated IP applies to non-SAP domains in a Salesforce Marketing Cloud Business Unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit, deliverability, sender-authentication-package, ip-warming

My project is having SFMC Business Unit which has a dedicated IP, but no SAP configured in the BU. I would like know if we can still perform IP warmup process on dedicated IP with non-SAP domain
i.e., configure a non-SAP domain in the BU and use it for sending emails to warm the dedicated IP. Please share your inputs on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: **Nope!**

Especially if you by *a non-SAP domain* mean a domain which is neither an SAP domain, nor a private domain. This would mean, that there is absolutely nothing which tells the guys in the receiving end, that you are an eligible sender, who is authorised to be using this IP address.

What is an SAP domain exactly? An SAP Domain includes link-wrapping (i.e. links, images, and anything else that would normally reflect SFMC, will reflect the chosen SAP domain instead). The domain is also authenticated with SPF/Sender ID and DKIM/Domain Keys.

It's the latter part, which is an issue. You will need to wait, until you have an SAP domain in place, since only then your emails will receive the proper authentication thanks to SPF/DKIM/DMARC etc. being in place.

I have written [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deliverability-lukas-lunow/), explaining the importance of email authentication, and it's impact on deliverability.